# An informal account of Godement resolution??

Tags: algebraic-topology, terminology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

while reading on the Godement resolution regarding stalks of a sheaf and the relation to the whole of the sheaf itself,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godement_resolution

I found this statement:

It allows one to view global, cohomological information about the sheaf in terms of local information coming from its stalks.

In some other place I cannot rememebr now it is said that it can be drived from the stalk(s) whether the sheaf is a monomorphis an epimorphism, or an isomorphism.

I would like to get an intuitive idea of how that works or how it is done. Something which couls be understood by a layman or a high school 18 yrs old kid.

Thnaks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused: a high schooler or a layman wouldn't even know about sheaves, and so trying to explain sheaf cohomology and resolutions to them seems like it would take much longer than a stack exchange answer has room for...

Comment: Whay I meant is not that a high schooler knows about sheaves....just how to explain something about it to him or her with minimal mathematical machinery....